# Conexión Básica a una Base de Datos con Ionic y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html5, ionic

Actualmente estoy estudiando el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles y me he encontrado Ionic, el cual hasta ahora me ha parecido interesante, así que he estudiado un poco lo básico y he estado tratando de conectarme a una base de datos teniendo una vista en HTML que a través de ng-click llama a un controlador que tiene la ruta de archivo PHP, el cual hace la respectiva consulta y retorna un mensaje básico para comprobar que la conexión y la consulta se hicieron.

Para ello estoy usando:

- Ionic framework: Instalado y probado previamente.
- JavaScript y PHP
- XAMPP con una base de datos llamada "datosingreso" en la cual trato de acceder con mi consulta a la tabla "tutorial"
- Plugin Allow-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) instalado y en "ON"
- Navegador Google Chrome

Código HTML

```
    // arriba de este código -> código generado por Ionic
   <div ng-controller="controller">
        <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive tabs">
            <a class="tab-item">
               <h4 style="color:white;" ng-click="registrar()">ALGO</h4>
            </a>
        </ion-footer-bar>
    </div>
    //abajo de este código -> código generado por Ionic
```

Código JavaScript:

```
(function (){

var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])  

app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.registrar = function(){
    $http.post("php/Conexion.php",{

    }).success(function(data){
       console.log("exito"); 
    });
}
});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
}())
```

Código PHP

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "datosingreso";

$dat0=1;
$dat1="uno";
$dat2="dos";
$dat3="tres";

session_start(); 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("error");

$sql="INSERT INTO `tutorial` (ID,Titulo,Descripcion,Imagen) VALUES('dat0','dat1','dat2','dat3')";

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("error");

echo $sql;
 ?>
```

El navegador me indica esto:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25005 POST http://localhost:8100/php/Conexion.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Pero no logro que funcione, probablemente me esté saltando algún paso o esté haciendo algo mal, ando atascado por este inconveniente. Espero que puedan darme una mano con esto, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Recibes algun error?

Comment: Este error "ionic.bundle.js:25005 POST http://localhost:8100/php/Conexion.php 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Estas probando desde el telefono?

Comment: Navegador desde mi pc

Comment: Probaste agregando <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />?

Comment: La app corre bien, tengo una imagen de presentación básica, un par de campos y dos botones, el único botón que tiene acción es el que estoy mostrando en el código de acá y el único error que me tira el navegador es el que te muestro.

Comment: Obvio, entiendo tu problema pero hay opciones que hacen que falle una llamada post, lo importante es siempre descartar primero si el servidor es el que falla(en este caso php) haz probado desde postman hacen el mismo post?

Comment: No conozco postman, ¿cómo se usa?

Comment: Postman es una aplicacion que te permite hacer peticiones de prueba a una url, pero como veo tu funcion ejecutala desde el navegador y ve si hace el insert como corresponde

Comment: Bien, voy a hacerlo y ya te respondo como me fue, gracias :)

Comment: Listo amigo, ya probé la consulta y efectivamente inserta la nueva fila en la tabla con los datos de prueba que allí coloco.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48474/discussion-between-sioesi-and-gutierrez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema solucionado, leyendo la documentación me di cuenta que en mi archivo JavaScript tenía un error en la dirección

```
$http.post("php/Conexion.php",{... //resto de código
```

La cambié por:

```
$http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Conexion.php"{... //resto de código
```

Gracias a eso comprobé la conexión a la base de datos, en la consola me imprime el mensaje, además revisé en las herramientas de desarrollador de Google y hace el respectivo echo.

De igual forma agradezco a @sioesi por su tiempo y atención a mi problema.